# How can I replace an entire string (a sentence) with another string in a file using VIM

Tags: vim

1. If I'm using the command line, what command can I used in Vim to change to edit mode from read-only mode for a file?
2. How can I search for a string "HELLO word" and replace with "hey guys" for the entire file? (Again, using the command line with Vim)

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I search for a string "HELLO word" and replace with "hey guys" for the entire file?

If you're trying to replace one string for another in the shell, then calling vim is not the best way to do it. Instead, you want to use `sed`.

```
sed -i 's/HELLO word/hey guys/g' filename.txt
```

Note that the `s/HELLO word/hey guys/g` syntax is what you would use in vim.

```
:%s/HELLO word/hey guys/g
```

Here is more about the `sed` tool: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files